# Semantic-ui-react; footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: css, reactjs, sticky-footer, semantic-ui-react

In my React app using semantic-ui-react, Have all the components in a `<Container fluid>` component.

The [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/footer-at-bottom-p437x?from-embed)

```
    <Container fluid>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="AppContent">
        <Content />
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </Container>
```

and the custom styles in the css file like below.

```
body {
  overflow-x: initial !important;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
.AppContent {
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem 1rem 2rem;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.Footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
}
```

Now I want the fotter to be at the buttom of the page.

adding `min-height:100vh` makes an unnecessary scroll bar when the content is few, and in this current code footer comes to the end of content, which can be middle of the page.

I got really confused about how the CSS works here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your footer should have a position of absolute instead of relative

```
.Footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
}
```

and then give the enclosing div `container` a position of relative. (You can add a class to the container.)

```
.container{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

This ensures that the footer is absolutely positioned relative to its parent.

Finally, since the height of the padding is 35px, you need to give a bottom padding to `AppContent` so the footer does not cover the content.

```
.AppContent {
  background-color: rgba(229, 255, 0, 0.404);
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem 35px 2rem;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Having absolute, makes the footer be at the end of initial page. when content grows the footer is the middle of the page. you can test it is the sandbox I have provided

Comment: Do you mean overriding the `Container` component style?  well anyway, I tried it, and it does not work. Footer absolute with container relative makes it look what it is right now, which is footer at the end of the content, not the end of the page

Comment: Just added `min-height: 100vh;` it was the missing part of the puzzle.

Comment: In this case, footer covers the last 35px of the content

Comment: Just added a bottom padding to the AppContent

Answer (score 0):

Your footer must be 'fixed' and no 'absolute'.

```css
.Footer {
  position: fixed;
  ...
}
```